# Stuck on an integral while solving an ODE

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I was solving 
$$\left(1+3e^{y/x}\right)\,\mathrm dx+3e^{y/x}\left(1-\dfrac xy\right)\,\mathrm dy=0\\ \implies \dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}= \dfrac{1+3e^{y/x}}{3e^{y/x}\left(\dfrac xy-1\right)}$$

As usual, I proceeded with $y=vx$.
$$v+x\dfrac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx}= \dfrac{1+3e^v}{3e^v\left(\dfrac 1v -1\right)}$$

Simplifying this, I found that 
$$\int\dfrac{3e^v(1-v)}{v(1+3ve^v)}\,\mathrm dv=\int\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{x}$$
(I might not be completely correct, so please check)

Now, I can't evaluate the integral on the left. How can I evaluate it?

Comment: Yes, I think so.